# Cannot install node-sass on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Im trying to install node-sass. I have both python 3 and 2.7 installed along with the visual studio build tools yet node gyp still fails.
Trying to uninstall and rebuild node-sass also gives the same result. How can i fix this.
This is the command i run:

```
npm install node-sass
```

This is the error i recieve:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\jsprojects\\halo\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\noble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\noble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\jsprojects\\halo\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\jsprojects\halo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\noble\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-29T16_53_55_944Z-debug.log
```

Comment: If you can use Dart Sass instead https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

Comment: @StephenGilboy, the node sass is actually a dependency within a project, im not sure how to exactly replace it

Comment: The error says python2 is missing. Try installing that first, then node-sass

Comment: I have had this issue, too. If it's a direct dependency, the best answer is to uninstall `node-sass`, install `sass`, and test to make sure you did not break anything. Dart sass doesn't require python, and node sass has lib sass as a dependency which was deprecated Oct 2020. https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You are using node version 16.13.1, I have found the solution to the  decreasing the version e get the node-v14.19.2